Can I travel to Italy as a tourist after my 1-year residence permit runs out?
(I’m from the UK)
I’m studying a Master’s degree in Italy. My residence permit runs out on the 12th of December, but I have exams in January and February. I’m not planning on staying in Italy after that. I also have a student visa which expires mid-2025.
Can I let the residence permit run out, and go to Italy to do my exams as a “tourist” (using the 90 days out of 180 total)? This way I can avoid the expenses and hassle of reapplying for a residence permit…

But you have a student visa, why do you need a residence permit to come for an exam?

See also https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/can-i-travel-out-of-italy-and-re-enter-if-my-type-d-visa-is-still-valid-and-perm?rq=1 (related question but that's about someone who cannot visit the Schengen area without a visa and there is no definitive answer)

I am in a similar situation. My visa is valid till 9th Jan 2025 but my permesso expired in Nov. 2024. Did it work for you?


Can I let the residence permit run out, and go to Italy to do my exams as a “tourist” (using the 90 days out of 180 total)?

Studies or exams are valid purposes for a short stay, which are not limited to tourism. There is no reason it should be an issue.
